# Intuition behind $\text{Re}(z)$ not being analytical

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Is there any way to "see" the reason for which the $\text{Re}(z)$ is not analytical?

Edit: **what I need is intuition(and maybe something graphic) and not definition of analytic function.**
So, the question is, why isn't $\text{Re}(z)$ analytic(does not satisfy the definition of an analytic function)?

Comment: Do you understand why complex conjugation is not analytic?

Comment: Perturb $z$ a little bit in the real direction, and then a bit in the imaginary direction. You get two entirely different results.

Comment: No, I do not understand that. My level on complex analysis is low.

Comment: $\text{Re}(z)$ does not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.  (This is essentially formalizing Umberto P.'s comment.)

Comment: @UmbertoP. What does it mean to perturb z?

Comment: @LandosAdam: Change by just a little bit.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, but I am not getting the full picture with Umberto's explanation.

Comment: I think the description of the question is incomplete.  It sounds like you need as a prerequisite an intuitive description of what "analytical" is.

Comment: I am taking a course on complex analysis for physics, but we have a seemingly different definition of analytical function. So, we don't do maths as rigorously as mathematicians(unfortunately)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a rigorous answer, but since you are looking for intuition...

If a function $f$ is differentiable at a point $z$, then there is a (complex) number $c$ for which $f(z+h) \approx f(z) + ch$. The number $c$ is the complex derivative, and $h$ is a complex number with small magnitude.

If $h$ is real, you have $Re(z+h) = Re(z) + h$ which indicates that $c = 1$.

If $h$ is imaginary, you have $Re(z+h) = Re(z)$ which indicates that $c = 0$.

Thus perturbing $z$ in the real direction and imaginary direction leads to different approximations, so that $f(z) = Re(z)$ isn't differentiable at $z$.

Comment: Why do the two approximations need to be equal in order for the function to be analytic?

Comment: That is (essentially) the *definition* of analytic.

Answer (score 1):

To say that this function is analytic at the origin is to say that the limit
$$
\lim_{z \to 0} \frac{\text{Re}(z)}{z}
$$
exists, where $z$ is a complex variable. (Definition of derivative). But this limit doesn't exist; it's $1$ if we approach the origin along the real axis and $0$ if we approach along the imaginary axis.